# Highmaps redraw bug after update points (with enabled zoom)

Tags: highcharts, highmaps

I found this highmaps version with lat/lon support (http://github.highcharts.com/latlon/highmaps.js) and then i created example to show what's happened when i try to zoom map and update points of the map dynamically. The common problem is that the points on the map are draggable (in the current zoom position) after `update()` method of point.

My example: http://jsfiddle.net/f97jkgz6/67/

I think function `map.redraw()` does not work properly, when zoom of map is enabled and more than default value.

Please, help me to find the solution of this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Ok. I found the solution. This was a bug of highmaps library. Now with version 1.1.0 or higher `redraw()` function works properly.

This is updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/f97jkgz6/69/